# How to change column values to rows in Access db

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, crosstab, unpivot, multiple-records

I have a table generated by a query in Access as something like this--

| Id | length | Height | Diameter | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-X(C1) | 1 | 4 | 100 | S W |
| 1-Y(C2) | 3 | 7 | 200 | N |

which I want to change to --

| Id | Feature | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-X(C1) | length | 1 |
| 1-X(C1) | Height | 4 |
| 1-X(C1) | Diameter | 100 |
| 1-X(C1) | code | S W |
| 1-Y(C2) | length | 3 |
| 1-Y(C2) | Height | 7 |
| 1-Y(C2) | Diameter | 200 |
| 1-Y(C2) | code | N |

I have tried using UNPIVOT function but it doesn't work,
I want the feature to be in a particular order(length, height, diameter, code)
I am using Access query design, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to UNION 4 queries. Something like:

```
select id, "length" as Feature, ("" & length) as value from myTable
union all
select id, "height" as Feature, height as value from myTable
union all
select id, "diameter" as Feature, diameter as value from myTable
```

Not sure value is not a reserved word ?

---

Since [value] is going to contain a mix of text and number, I guess you will have to convert it all to text. I did it for the first row, just to show.

Comment: Got the expected result but the Feature is not in any order for each Id, I want the feature to be in a particular order(length, height, diameter, code). any ideas?

Comment: Update your question so it is complete - @iDevlop has answered your question as is.

Answer (score 0):

I've not fully tested, but you could have a secondary table containing the fields, in the order you expect.

So in this case i had `piv` and `piv_order` in a table called `pivs`.  And length as order 1, height as 2 and so on.  Probably not the most ideal solution as would need to maintain this table, or the most efficient.

```
SELECT distinct t1.id, p.piv as Feature, 
DLookUp(p.piv,"table1","id=" & t1.id) AS FeatureValue 
FROM table1 AS t1, pivs AS p
ORDER BY t1.id, p.piv_order;
```